# Django unable to change timezone from UTC format

Tags: python, django, datetime

> settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

> models.py

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ip_add = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data = models.TextField()
```

I am making a post request to my URL, which stores the data to db (using sqlite) through my view. The datetime field always stores the time in UTC format (which was the default setting for TIME_ZONE variable in settings.py)

I've changed TIME_ZONE to 'Asia/Calcutta; after referring this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

But still datetime is being stored in UTC format. I tried changing USE_TZ to False after googling for this problem but that didn't work for me.

I'm simply querying the data from db in python shell. i.e.

```
x = Mymodel()

for i in range(len(x)):
    print x[i].__dict__
```

Please advise how to change the timezone to 'Asia/Calcutta'.

Comment: Are you running your Django server on Windows? If so, is your Windows timezone set to 'Asia/Calcutta'?

Comment: Running on mac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have tried with below settings and it worked fine for me.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = False
```

Needed USE_L10N setting to False as well, format localization is controlled by this setting (applied to numbers and dates).

See below link :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 0):

I have ran some tests with my own model (Django v1.11.6), and it seems to work for me.

Try to do some tests (python manage.py shell) like:

```
from MyApp.models import Mymodel
testmodel = Mymodel(ip_add="something", data="something")
testmodel.save()
testmodel.datatime
```

When USE_TZ is enabled it has a tzinfo:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 21, 13, 43, 8, 718392, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

When USE_TZ is disabled it does not have a tzinfo:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 21, 15, 45, 25, 471765)
```

I did both of these tests at approx. 15:45 my local time.

This is stored in my database:

```
2017-10-21 13:43:08.718392 (with timezone enabled)
2017-10-21 15:45:25.471765 (without timezone enabled)
```

The datetime table column type is datetime(6)

One other thing. You say you are doing a POST. The documentation sais about using 'auto_now_add': "Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored".
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: OK, I have set USE_TZ = False in my settings.py and restarted the server. But still new records are being added with UTC timezone. Don't think it has worked for me unless I missed something.